# Careers 'Your Profile' Stats - Incorrect (duplicate) text

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In the 'Your Profile' box where it shows the statics such as number of views, it appears that the last text is incorrectly a duplicate of the text above it.

[image: My Profile Stats + Freehand circle]

Should the bottom 'Email inquiries from employers' be something like 'Responses to employer inquiries' instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is in fact exactly what it should be... and will be as soon as we push changes to prod later today.